# UICollectionCell and UITableViewCell background color behind corner

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I have the situation shown in the image below:

[image]

Can I make the little view behind the corners to be something different than the cell's background color.

I've tried the following code:

```
 cell.lblActionTitle.text = sectionValue.data?.title
        cell.lblActionTitle.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
        cell.lblActionTitle.textColor = .black
        cell.lblActionTitle.backgroundColor = .yellow
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layoutSubviews()
```

Comment: Put a container view inside your cell content view and put all UI elements on this container view after making rounded corners of container view you can freely change background color of cell content view which will reflect as color of small area  at corners.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: hmm. The cell is custom, and if I write something like `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black`, the whole cell is black -- except the little corner edges. Can you elaborate? Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I made an image using my favorite graphics program, and used that as a background. The result is:

[image]